# Synonym for "specially crafted", deliberately made-up example

Tags: synonyms

I remember I've come across an adjective for a "***weird computer program, obviously made-up to prove a point***".

Any idea what that word might have been?

Comment: I'm not entirely certain whether _recherché_ is appropriate (apart from it being French).

Comment: Niche? Proof of concept?

Comment: *Program* as in *course of study* or *software* or *planned order of events*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's not specific to software, the adjective you might be looking for could be:

> **contrived**
>
> *adjective*
>
> deliberately created rather than arising naturally or spontaneously

A "specially crafted, deliberately made up example" is almost the classic case of something being *contrived*.

As an example: *the code was contrived to trigger the worst-case performance of the system, in a way that no normal program ever would.*